# Bubble Sort method not working with Linked List in C

Tags: c

I am trying to implement a bubble sort method into a linked list data structure, but when running it through a test harness, it doesn't do anything. Any suggestions?

Here is my source code:

```
void set_sort (set_t * the_set)
{
    assert (the_set);
    set_node_t *current;
    current = the_set->head;
    int sorted = 1;
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < the_set->set_size; x++) {
        //we dont do it if this is the last value
        if (x + 1 == the_set->set_size) {
            continue;
        }
        if (current->data > current->next->data) {
            sorted = 0;
            int temp = &current->next->data;
            current->next->data = current->data;
            current->data = temp;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    if (!sorted) {
        set_sort (the_set);
    }

}
```

EDIT WITH HEADER FILE

```
#ifndef _set_h_
#define _set_h_

#include <stdbool.h>
#include "common.h"

/* Create a basic singly-linked list.*/
/*This code has been sourced from Mike Mcallistar, Assignment 5 Solutions*/

typedef struct _set_node_t {
        test_type_t *data;
        struct _set_node_t *next;
        struct _set_node_t *below;
} set_node_t;

/* the set itself keeps track of the head and the tail of the linked list */
typedef struct {

        int set_size;
        bool ready;
        set_node_t *head;
        set_node_t *tail;
        int set_level;
} set_t;


bool set_init(set_t *the_set);
void set_destroy(set_t *the_set);
bool set_add(set_t *the_set, test_type_t *item_to_add);
bool set_delete(set_t *the_set, test_type_t *item_to_remove);
bool set_find( set_t *the_set, test_type_t *item_to_find);
void set_sort(set_t *the_set);
void set_enumerate(set_t *the_set);
#endif
```

Comment: If you are not required to use `bubblesort` for an assignment, just be aware it is one of the *least* efficient sort routines you can choose. `quicksort` or `mergesort` are far more efficient. (for everything over 16 or so elements)

Comment: sorry about that, I've been working on this method for 2hrs and have gotten very sloppy with my formatting. Will fix for next time

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin This is mostly true although subjective.  It's very good at sorting mostly sorted lists with only a couple of rows out of place in a large list.  Other than that it can be beaten fairly easily as you point out.

Comment: @couling agreed. The bubblesort for less than 100 or so makes little difference in efficiency, but after that its efficiency quickly tanks compared to the others. By the time you get to 250,000 elements, it is orders of magnitude slower than the others. If you look at the GNU source for `qsort`, you will see it uses a blended `quicksort` and `mergesort` routines. IIRC it uses mergesort for less than 16 elements and quicksort for everything above. Apple uses more of a straight `quicksort` in its `qsort` algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something seems very wrong with this.

```
int temp = &current->next->data;     // Assignes a pointer into temp
current->next->data = current->data; // Copies current into next
current->data = temp;                // Copies the pointer into data
```

This is unlikely to do nothing. It's quite likely to corrupt your data.

Could it be as simple as to change the first of these lines to:

```
int temp = current->next->data;
```

**Edit**

Cleaning up your code a little I get to this:

```
void set_sort(set_t *the_set)
{
    assert(the_set);
    int sorted;
    int x;
    do {
        set_node_t *current = the_set->head;
        sorted = 1;
        for( x = 0; x < the_set->set_size - 1; x++){
            if(current->data > current->next->data){
                sorted = 0;
                int temp = current->next->data;
                current->next->data = current->data;
                current->data = temp;
            }
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    while (!sorted);
}
```

Removing the use of unnecessary recursion removes the risk of causing a stack overflow.  Removing the continue makes the code marginally quicker (I believe).  Removing the spurious use of the pointer should fix your code.

If your code isn't fixed by this then then you will need to post the definition of `set_node_t`, its possible your comparison is not working (`if (current->data > current->next->data)`).

**Edit 2**

As comments and updated question has now pointed out you need to perform your comparison on the data itself and not the pointer to the data.

```
if(*(current->data) > *(current->next->data)){
```

Comment: Thank you for cleaning this up for me, I see now how I could condense certain aspects of my above code. Sort still doesn't do anything, I will edit my above post to add my whole header file(definitions of node and set structs)

Comment: If `data` is pointer, then you compare pointers instead of real data.

Comment: @user1034749 what would I do differently to show this?

Comment: I suppose if you replace code in answer above with `if(*(current->data) > *(current->next->data))` and use `*` in code where you swap values, then all should works fine

Comment: @couling header posted, sorry for the wait

Comment: Each of the inner loops moves the largest value to the end of the list, so a max counter could be set to set_count before starting the outer loop, and decremented before each inner loop. | max_count = the_set->set_size;| ... | do{ ... | max_count--; | for (x = 0; x < max_count; x++){ | ...